# Select 2 counts from a join query

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

This query always returns "num_of_accounts" the same as num_of_users
but if i remove the second join with lists_user_assignment
num_of_accounts is correct

```
  select lists.*, count(lists_account_assignment.id) as num_of_accounts, count(lists_user_assignment.id) as num_of_users
from lists
left join lists_account_assignment on lists.id = lists_account_assignment.lists_id
left join lists_user_assignment on lists.id = lists_user_assignment.lists_id
where lists.tenant_id = 1
group by lists.id
```

Not sure if this is the right way to get 2 counts in a query. Also, if this query will be expensive or not. Would appreciate help.

Comment: 2 counts? I only see one

Comment: Why do you need to join `lists_user_assignment`? It doesn't seem to do anything in the query?

Comment: why dont you use union. make 2 different queries for 2 different counts and then execute using union.

Comment: my bad, dint include the second count. updated the query

Comment: We need table definitions/sample data/multiplicities to answer this intelligibly.  Which of the two RDBMSs are you using for this?  Learn what/how to use an EXPLAIN plan, which can tell you "how expensive".  In SQL it's considered bad practice to use `SELECT *`, for a number of reasons - always list out the columns you're using.  Note that the MySQL "feature" of allowing `GROUP BY` without all selected columns being in an aggregate function or the clause is inherently dangerous - you'll likely get correct results here, but may otherwise receive undefined results in other queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a COUNT(DISTINCT ..):-

```
SELECT lists.*, 
       Count(DISTINCT lists_account_assignment.id) AS num_of_accounts, 
       Count(DISTINCT lists_user_assignment.id)    AS num_of_users 
FROM   lists 
       LEFT JOIN lists_account_assignment 
              ON lists.id = lists_account_assignment.lists_id 
       LEFT JOIN lists_user_assignment 
              ON lists.id = lists_user_assignment.lists_id 
WHERE  lists.tenant_id = 1 
GROUP  BY lists.id
```

Comment: this worked great, just want to know, is that query considered expensive, since i am count from 2 tables?

Comment: Joins on an integer key are fast. The bit that will take the time is probably the distinct. But the over head of doing 2 different queries would probably be far greater.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SELECT      L.*, count(Acc.id) AS NoOfAccounts
FROM        lists L
LEFT JOIN   lists_account_assignment Acc
ON          L.id = Acc.lists_id
LEFT JOIN   lists_user_assignment U
ON          L.id = U.lists_id
AND         L.tenant_id = 1  
GROUP BY    L.id
```

Comment: Is this query just rewritten using alias?